# I can't see how many that has installed my android game

Tags: android, google-play

I made an android game and I uploaded and published it. And I installed it my phone. But I can't see how many installs on its google play page.

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andgame.evenodd233

Comment: How many times I have to wait? more than 6 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the statistics are not updated in real time, especially in the user-visible part of Play.

As a developper / publisher, you should have access to the developer console *(you do : it's where you published your app)*.

There, you'll find more statistics, which will be more precise and more detailed than what's visible *(or what will be visible)* on the user-part of Play.

Still, there too, stats might not be updated in real-time.

And as a reference, quoting a few sentences from [the help page "Application statistics"](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628&topic=16285&ctx=topic) :

> In Google Play Developer Console, you can currently view the following
>   statistics about your published application 
> [...] 
> These
>   statistics are **refreshed on a daily basis**.

Comment: I can't see in developer console too.How many times I have to wait? more than 6 hours?

Comment: Not sure what's implied by "daily" ; but, especially for a new app that's been published today, I wouldn't start panicking right away :-) I'd said wait until tomorrow *(something like 24h)*